# DotNetOpenAuth - A property with the name 'OriginalHttpRequestUri' is not present Exception

Tags: c#, .net, webforms, dotnetopenauth

I am attempting to implement the example from the DotNetOpenAuth Service Provider solution but instead of using OpenId for authentication, I am using Forms Authentication.

I copied and pasted the Consumer example but removed the Service Reference and added a new service reference pointing to my WCF service.

Getting of the Access Tokens is working great and I can see them appearing in my database table, however, as soon as I attempt to access data, it is failing on this line in the OAuthAuthorizationManager class:

```
Uri requestUri = OperationContext.Current.IncomingMessageProperties["OriginalHttpRequestUri"] as Uri;
```

Is there something I am missing somewhere? It seems that this property should exist because I don't see where it is manually added anywhere in the original. I copied and pasted the Web.config from the sample Service Provider project and all of my files are named the same.

Let me know if there is any more information needed or if anyone wants me to email them the sample project to look at.

Thanks for any assistance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Uri requestUri = operationContext.RequestContext.RequestMessage.Properties.Via;
```

I think it is a more secure way of finding the original HTTP information.